# javascript jquery selecting radio buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a php script that outputs many divs, in each div is a radio button with a specific value. I want to create a better user experience by having the radio button selected when the div is clicked, which isn't much of a problem when I use jquery. The problem is, when the radio button itself is clicked and not the div, the following clicks don't have the effect of selecting the radio button any more. I also tried to remove the checked attribute on every radio button before checking the selected one, but this doesn't work. Here is how I do it:

```
$(".fontCellDiv").click(function(){ 
     $(this).find("input").attr("checked", true);
 });
```

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: not able to understand clearly what you want and post html or fiddle link plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

From the documentation:

> ## Attributes vs. Properties
>
> The difference between attributes and properties can be important in
> specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes
> took property values into account when retrieving some attributes,
> which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop()
> method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while
> .attr() retrieves attributes.

Comment: yes that was the solution, I still don't understand why attr() doesn't do the job though.

Comment: Read the entire documentation I've sent you. Also, if an answer solves your problem, you're supposed to "accept" it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".fontCellDiv").click(function(){ 
    $(".fontCellDiv").find("input").removeAttr('checked');
    $(this).find("input").attr("checked", true);
});
```

```css
.fontCellDiv{
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #0f0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fontCellDiv">
    <input name="sameGroup" type="radio" />
</div>
<div class="fontCellDiv">
    <input name="sameGroup" type="radio" />
</div>
<div class="fontCellDiv">
    <input name="sameGroup" type="radio" />
</div>
```

Check this sample.